# Detecting sections of text in a document using yolo

Tags: object, detection, yolo, darknet

I wanted to know if Darknet Yolo or other Object Detection algorithms can be used to pick up sections of text in a document like an IRS 1099 form - which has areas of text that form distinct sections. Can yolo be trained to pick up sections of text as objects?

[image]